# UDF's in a Loop?

Tags: c++

I want this program to ask the user if they would like another conversion (at the end) and to do so if they select yes, until they say no. I was thinking maybe a do/while loop would work, but I wasn't sure of the nature. I've never done it with UDF's before so any help is greatly appreciated!

It is a polar <--> rectangular coordinate converter.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do a loop in your `main` function

```
int main()
{
    // Variable declarations
    float mag;
    double angl, x, y;
    int num;

    do   
    {
        // Function calls
        readit(mag, angl, x, y, num);
        calcit(mag, angl, x, y, num);
        writeit(mag, angl, x, y, num);
    }
    while(continueit());

    return 0;
}
```

You then have a function `bool continueit()` which returns true if the user wants to continue with another conversion, or false if not.

```
bool continueit()
{
    std::cout << "do another conversion? 'yes' to continue\n";

    std::string answer;
    std::cin >> answer;

    return answer == "yes";
}
```

If desired you can check for `'y'` or uppercase/lowercase, but the semantics will be largely the same.